# Возможно ли создать TVMLJS-приложение, работающее без серверной части?

Tags: objective-c, swift, tvos

Как все мы знаем, при разработке приложений для платформы tvOS можно использовать JS-фреймворк под названием TVMLJS. В частности, среда разработки XCode предоставляет возможность создать демонстрационный проект на базе этого фреймворка. Однако для того чтобы запустить данное приложение нам необходимо развернуть сервер, который будет поставлять данные для приложения (по сути приложение должно просто отображать эту информацию). Я знаю, что Apple продвигает именно такую концепцию разработки приложений. Но если у меня нет возможности развернуть подобный сервер, то как мне тогда разрабатывать приложения с TVMLJS? Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать это без сервера (и без использования TVMLKit).

Comment: как это нет возможности? и локальный не получается?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Возможно я неточно выразил свой мысль в вопросе. В XCode при создании проекта я указал "tvOS" -> "TVML application". После запуска такого приложения я вижу сообщение "Error launching application" и в коде вижу, что приложение пытается получить данные по **http://localhost:9001**.

Comment: интернет завален примерами таких серверов - скачайте и запустите локально. и будет у вас сервер на localhost:9001

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Не в этом проблема. Я хочу такой проект опубликовать в магазине, клиенты же не смогут ничего открыть на localhost:9001 (локальный запуск приложения меня не интересует). Потому и спрашиваю, можно ли обойти как-нибудь это подключение с целью забрать данные? Можно ли их просто из файла считать например?

Comment: можно http://thejustinwalsh.com/objective-c/tvml/2015/09/20/tvml-without-the-webserver.html

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Спасибо огроменное! Попробую запустить и тогда отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko решение по ссылке является рабочим, мог бы засчитать в качестве ответа.

Comment: у меня руки отвалятся столько переводить